# Is it possible to query to find all records for a given day that are all of type JSON?

Tags: sql, oracle

At some point in the past the data column values (CLOB) were switched over from CSV to JSON.
There is no documentation on when this took place.

I cannot do an order by on the select because records can get updated and the value gets replaced with JSON. So it may appear that the earliest record is on that date but if I search for all records on that day I can see a mix of CSV and JSON data for the day.

Is there a way in only SQL to find the day where all records are JSON as this would be the more than likely date where the switchover took place? Or search for a range of days where all the data in the CONTENT are all of type JSON?

e.g. DB columns & dummy data

```
DATE_CREATED | DATE_UPDATED | CONTENT
01-APR-12      01-APR-12      <XML STUFF>
01-APR-12      01-APR-12      <XML STUFF>
01-APR-12      21-JUN-20      {JSON STUFF}
05-APR-12      05-APR-12      <XML STUFF>
01-APR-14      08-MAR-20      {JSON STUFF}
01-APR-16      21-JUN-21      <XML STUFF>
01-APR-14      11-SEP-22      {JSON STUFF}
01-APR-14      01-JAN-21      {JSON STUFF}
01-APR-17      21-JUN-19      <XML STUFF>
11-FEB-23      11-FEB-20      {JSON STUFF}
11-FEB-23      11-FEB-20      {JSON STUFF}
11-FEB-23      11-FEB-20      {JSON STUFF}
```

I need a way to query the database to find the DATE_CREATED when all the data for the CONTENT was JSON

OUTPUT:

```
DATE_CREATED | DATE_UPDATED | CONTENT
11-FEB-23      11-FEB-20      {JSON STUFF}
11-FEB-23      11-FEB-20      {JSON STUFF}
11-FEB-23      11-FEB-20      {JSON STUFF}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `IS JSON` operator:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  content IS JSON;
```

If that is not supported then you can create a user-defined function to check if the `CONTENT` value is valid JSON by trying to parse it and catching any exceptions:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION is_json(value IN CLOB) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    json JSON_ELEMENT_T;
  BEGIN
    json := JSON_ELEMENT_T.parse(value);
    RETURN 1;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RETURN 0;
  END;
/
```

Then use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  is_json(content) = 1;
```

*Note: In later Oracle versions you can declare the function in a sub-query factoring clause; however, in those versions `IS JSON` will probably be supported.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
create table table_name(date_created DATE, content CLOB);

INSERT INTO table_name(date_created, content)
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-01', 'abcde'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-02', '{}'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-03', 'xyz{}'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-04', '["abc"]' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-05', '{}'      FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DATE_CREATED | CONTENT |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-02 00:00:00 | {} |
| 2023-01-04 00:00:00 | ["abc"] |
| 2023-01-05 00:00:00 | {} |

---

If you want to get the earliest row which that row and all rows created later are valid JSON then you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY date_created
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( valid_json {- valid_json* -} $ )
  DEFINE valid_json AS content IS JSON
)
```

Which, outputs:

| DATE_CREATED | CONTENT |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-04 00:00:00 | ["abc"] |

If you want to include `date_updated` then unpivot the date columns and use the same technique.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QMnwJ-vp)

---

#### Update:

If you want the first date when, for that entire day and all later days, the `content` was valid JSON then just use the previous query and check that the first matched row is on a later day to the previous row:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY date_created
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( first_valid_json {- valid_json* -} $ )
  DEFINE
    first_valid_json AS  content IS JSON
                     AND (  PREV(date_created) IS NULL
                         OR PREV(date_created) < TRUNC(date_created) ),
    valid_json       AS content IS JSON
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3LmNoVCW)

Comment: We ran into issues where running a select * from table where column is JSON would end up freezing after about an hour of running. We have millions of records and so I wanted to try and change how we approach the SQL select to find it by date ranging to limit it in order to avoid the issue with select *.

Comment: @edjm If you want to filter on a range then add a filter in the `WHERE` clause. `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE content IS JSON AND date_created >= DATE '2023-01-01' AND date_created < DATE '2023-02-01';`

Comment: @MTO I need to find the EXACT CREATE_DATE when data for a full day was all JSON

Answer (score 0):

Text of the question combined with sample data provided and the result are somehow confusing. There are rows in sample data that are updated before being created but if what you need is:
quote: "***I need a way to query the database to find the DATE_CREATED when all the data for the CONTENT was JSON***" then you could use Not Exists to do the selection, though the result is a bit different compared to your expected result.

```sql
WITH          -- Sample data
    tbl (DATE_CREATED, DATE_UPDATED, CONTENT) AS
    (   Select To_Date('01-APR-12', 'dd-MON-yy'), To_Date('01-APR-12', 'dd-MON-yy'), '<XML STUFF>'  From Dual Union All
        Select To_Date('01-APR-12', 'dd-MON-yy'), To_Date('01-APR-12', 'dd-MON-yy'), '<XML STUFF>'  From Dual Union All
        Select To_Date('01-APR-12', 'dd-MON-yy'), To_Date('21-JUN-20', 'dd-MON-yy'), '{JSON STUFF}' From Dual Union All
        Select To_Date('05-APR-12', 'dd-MON-yy'), To_Date('05-APR-12', 'dd-MON-yy'), '<XML STUFF>'  From Dual Union All
        Select To_Date('01-APR-14', 'dd-MON-yy'), To_Date('08-MAR-20', 'dd-MON-yy'), '{JSON STUFF}' From Dual Union All
        Select To_Date('01-APR-16', 'dd-MON-yy'), To_Date('21-JUN-21', 'dd-MON-yy'), '<XML STUFF>'  From Dual Union All
        Select To_Date('01-APR-14', 'dd-MON-yy'), To_Date('11-SEP-22', 'dd-MON-yy'), '{JSON STUFF}' From Dual Union All
        Select To_Date('01-APR-14', 'dd-MON-yy'), To_Date('01-JAN-21', 'dd-MON-yy'), '{JSON STUFF}' From Dual Union All
        Select To_Date('01-APR-17', 'dd-MON-yy'), To_Date('21-JUN-19', 'dd-MON-yy'), '<XML STUFF>'  From Dual Union All
        Select To_Date('11-FEB-20', 'dd-MON-yy'), To_Date('11-FEB-23', 'dd-MON-yy'), '{JSON STUFF}' From Dual Union All
        Select To_Date('11-FEB-20', 'dd-MON-yy'), To_Date('11-FEB-23', 'dd-MON-yy'), '{JSON STUFF}' From Dual Union All
        Select To_Date('11-FEB-20', 'dd-MON-yy'), To_Date('11-FEB-23', 'dd-MON-yy'), '{JSON STUFF}' From Dual 
        )
--  
--   Main SQL
Select  t.DATE_CREATED, t.DATE_UPDATED, t.CONTENT
From    tbl t
Where   SubStr(t.CONTENT, 1, 1) || SubStr(CONTENT, -1) = '{}' And 
        Not Exists (Select 1 From tbl 
                    Where DATE_CREATED = t.DATE_CREATED And SubStr(t.CONTENT, 1, 1) || SubStr(CONTENT, -1) !=  '{}')
--
--  R e s u l t :
DATE_CREATED DATE_UPDATED CONTENT     
------------ ------------ ------------
11-FEB-23    11-FEB-20    {JSON STUFF}
11-FEB-23    11-FEB-20    {JSON STUFF}
11-FEB-23    11-FEB-20    {JSON STUFF}
01-APR-14    01-JAN-21    {JSON STUFF}
01-APR-14    11-SEP-22    {JSON STUFF}
01-APR-14    08-MAR-20    {JSON STUFF}
```

Note:
The expression SubStr(t.CONTENT, 1, 1) || SubStr(CONTENT, -1) = '{}' doesn't test the content for being proper JSON or not - if you need that check as well then you should use some other method depending on Oracle version you are working with.

Comment: I'm reading over your post but to try and clarify,  "I need a way to query the database to find the first DATE_CREATED when all the data for the CONTENT was JSON for the entire day"

Comment: @edjm Sorry, I just don't get it. What does it mean "query the database" - is it one table or more? If more, there is a lack of sample data so I thought it is just one. Second, the "first DATE_CREATED" I would consider the oldest one and with sample data provided it would be 01-APR-14. For that DATE_CREATED in your sample data all CONTENTS are JSON the same as for 11-FEB-23.

Comment: @edjm Also, if there are times within the dates (obviously there are - not in sample data, though) just use TRUNC(DATE_CREATED).

Comment: @d r Just a single database table.